# Sails app using angular-ui-router fails to load state based views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, sails.js

I'm attempting to use angular-ui-router to display templates, based on state. Currently, i'm not getting errors in the terminal. In the console, I see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined" and "uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined". This makes me think I'm not instantiating modules properly. New to angularjs and hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction. **app.js**

```html
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngMessages', 'app-templates'])
  .run(function($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if (!Auth.authorize(toState.data.access)) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $state.go('anon.login');
      }
    });
  });
```

**And, routes.js.**

```js
angular.module('app')
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, AccessLevels) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('anon', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        data: {
          access: AccessLevels.anon
        }
      })
      .state('anon.index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
      })
      .state('anon.login', {
        url: '/login',
        template: 'auth/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
      })
      .state('anon.register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: 'auth/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
      });

    $stateProvider
      .state('user', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        data: {
          access: AccessLevels.user
        }
      })
      .state('user.messages', {
        url: '/messages',
        template: 'user/messages.html',
        controller: 'MessagesController'
      });

  });
```

Comment: Each time I try to access a nested route w/ Angular UI it seems to fall back to SailsJS rendered views.  The error I see in the console is making reference to localhost:1337 instead of my front-end app, which is on localhost:9000